# MonoTouch.Dialog: Change Color of Section

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Normally to change the characteristics (Font, color) of a Section in Plain mode we have to create an entire view from scratch.

In cases where a simple change is needed in color/size, is there an easier way to do this?

Here's what I tend to do:

```
    var header = new UILabel(new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, 25)){
      Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (22),
      TextColor = UIColor.White,
      BackgroundColor = SomethingPretty,
      Text = "Something"
};

Section secGroup = new Section(header);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the simplest way:

```
var header = new UILabel(new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, 25)){
  Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (22),
  TextColor = UIColor.White,
  BackgroundColor = SomethingPretty,
  Text = "Something"
};

Section secGroup = new Section(header);
```

Comment: You can alternatively create you own sizing source by overriding CreateSizingSource() and in your source override GetViewForHeader(). But still, you'd end up creating the view from scratch.